# Resize a control so the top moves not the bottom?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a winform with a tabcontrol on it at the bottom part of my form. I resize the tabcontrol to the correct size but it resizes downwards, IE the top part of the form doesn't move. Is there a way to have the top of the tabcontrol move up to the new position instead?

[image: Old size and new size with new position]

Comment: You may try Layout Control by DevExpress.

Comment: Add both the tabcontrol(dock fill) in two different panel , with first panel as Dock Top with a height and 2nd panel with a dock fill. When you want to change the size of first one, just set the height of the first panel.

Comment: And the problem is ... ? Every `Control` has `Location` (upper left corner) and `Size`, *re-sizing* (aka changing `Size`) means .. changing size, and **not** `Location`. So, why do you want to change location when changing size?

Comment: Thank for the help. all sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        tabControl2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

We can using Dock property or Anchor property, do everything as we want to locate control...

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted to happen.